# Pytorch weights sampling on TrainLoader

Tags: python, pytorch

```
# sklearn's dataloader, useful for large dataset
# it also does data shuffling
trainDT = CustomDataset(X_train, y_train)
testDT = CustomDataset(X_test, y_test)
global trainloader


#Calculate weights for samples (more emphasis for more recent samples)
#Weightage of 2 for the last 1972 data instances
sample_weights = []
sample_weights = DataFrame(sample_weights)
#sample_weights = torch.tensor(sample_weights)

sample_weights[5000:6971] = 2
sample_weights[0:5000] = 1

#Assign weights to all samples
sample_weights_all = sample_weights[trainDT]


#Add in sample weights for index samples
weighted_sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(
    weights=sample_weights,
    num_samples=len(sample_weights_all),
    replacement=False
)


trainloader = DataLoader(trainDT, batch_size=500, shuffle=True,sampler=weighted_sampler)
testloader = DataLoader(testDT, batch_size=500,shuffle=False)
```

Hi , What I am trying to do is to assign 2 X weightage for the last 1972 samples as seen in the code below. The following error occurred. Is anyone able to advise how do I get this through. The rationale is to place more emphasis on more recent samples (last 1972 samples).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "OptunaTest", line 615, in <module>
    n_instances, n_features, scores = run_analysis()
  File "OptunaTest", line 377, in run_analysis
    sample_weights_all = sample_weights[trainDT]
  File "/home/shar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2995, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/shar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: <__main__.CustomDataset object at 0x7f0399e82c88>
```

Comment: `sample_weights[5000:6971] = 2; sample_weights[0:5000] = 1` is not working as you might think. It does not allocate the memory. In this case, I suggest just using `sample_weights = np.empty(6971)`.

Comment: @yuchenzhong, thanks, np.empty(6971) merely creates the shape of the array and not its values. In this case , I am looking to populate the first 5000 instances with weightage of 1 and the last 1971 instances with weightage of 2 (more emphasis). May I know for this case , after creating the shape with np.empty , how do I create populate its content? Thanks in advance